# gcov, make, cmake, ctest coverage build

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, code-coverage, gcov

I have a project, which consist of my project and multiply external ones, which a building together, as mine is using others. It's structure looks like:

```
external
 - subproj1
 - subproj2
another_external_project
myproject
 - src
 - tests
```

I'm building it first running "cmake" to configure it and find if all dependencies are met and then "make" to compile it. Tests are run with "ctest". 
The thing is I need to have coverage only for my myproject/src directory.

What I have tried to generate gcda files:

- adding CPP_FLAGS "-coverage" to make, but I see only some files and there is no one needed coverage file in my project
- adding coverage flags to CMakelist, but still the same

The questions are:
1) what step should I add coverage flags? at configuration? or at "make"?
2) If so, should I add that flags to ctest CMakelist  or not?

Comment: One addition, I'm trying to do as written: https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake  but getting an error that there are no gcda files...

Comment: you forgot the linker flag too

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found the answer.

The thing is when configuring with cmake, I should have passed it as:

```
cmake -D"CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-g -O2 -w -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" -D"CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-g -O2 -w -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
```

while then building application with make, I should pass other variables but with the same flags:

```
make -j`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` CFLAGS='-g -O2 -w -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage' CXXFLAGS='-g -O2 -w -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage'
```

After that I run tests and generate the reports.

Comment: is it possible to include these arguments in the CMakeLists.txt file? And are you running tests with ctest?

Comment: here is a decent article: https://jhbell.com/using-cmake-and-gcov and code: https://github.com/jhbell/cmake-gcov